# How can I reduce Sequelize request time? (AJAX response takes too much time)

Tags: node.js, ajax, datatable, sequelize.js, server-side-rendering

I requested AJAX get method using Sequelize to give dataTable data. Since it took too long (about 1,800ms) to get about 4,000 pieces of data, I used `offset` and `limit` options to perform server side pagination. However, whether it brings 4,000 or 10 pieces of data, the time it takes was similar (1,800ms).

How can I make my Sequelize request faster?

I want a time of at most 100ms. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
const data = models.User.findAll({
    subQuery: false,
    where: {
      UserId: user.id,
    },
    attributes: [
      'id',
      [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('caps')), 'no_caps'],
    ],
    include: [{
      model: models.Post,
      attributes: [],
    }],
    order: [
      ['id', 'ASC'],
    ],
    offset: req.query.start,
    limit: req.query.length,
});
```

Comment: Did you estimate an amount of time that is needed to execute an SQL query directly?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I just checked the time needed to execute an raw SQL query. But SQL query works well. It takes just 200ms. Can you give me more suggestion?

Comment: So the next step is to calculate the time of the findAll call by wrapping it with console.time('label') and console.timeEnd('label')

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did your next step, and it says that findAll call takes 1800ms. So I believe that something is wrong with sequelize or node.js. What can be wrong with them?

Comment: Can you execute some simple sequelize request before this request and then again estimate the time of the original request?

Comment: I see your point. Now I've seen what's taking it a long time. When 'findAll call' includes(joins) a particular model's attributes, request time increases very much. This doesn't happen when it includes other models. Do you have any suggestions? You've been a lot of help.